# Excel 2007 - Can't combine these three formulas into one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have three separate formulas each in it's own cell.

Each formula has multiple criteria looking at data within a workbook.

The way the formulas work is that only one should produce a result and where the two that don't they do nothing (the cell remains blank).

I think the worksheet is messy and it would be nicer to have all three formulas in the same cell. I wonder if there is a better, cleaner way.

As I said only ONE can produce a positive (true) result (where something is displayed in the cell) but all three can produce a false result in which case the cell remains blank so they should not clash.

it would be something like:

```
Formula 1 False (do nothing)
Formula 2 True (Display result)
Formula 3 False (do nothing)
```

or

```
Formula 1 True (Display result)
Formula 2 False (do nothing)
Formula 3 False (do nothing)
```

or

```
Formula 1 False (do nothing)
Formula 2 False (do nothing)
Formula 3 True (Display result)
```

or

```
Formula 1 False (do nothing)
Formula 2 False (do nothing)
Formula 3 False (do nothing)
(cell remains blank)
```

I have tried for hours and I just can not seem to get this to work with Excel giving errors.

It does not matter which order the formulas are in when combined as long as only one can return a True result.

My three formulas are:

```
=IF(AND(Add_CD_Information!B23=3), "<hr style=""color:#919090; background-color:#919090; height:1px; border:none;"">", "")

=IF(AND(Add_CD_Information!B23={1},Add_CD_Information!B48<>""), "<br>", "")

=IF(AND(Add_CD_Information!B23={1},Add_CD_Information!B25={2}), "<hr style=""color:#919090; background-color:#919090; height:1px; border:none;"">", "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is.. :

```
=IF(AND(Add_CD_Information!B23=3), "<hr style=""color:#919090; background-color:#919090; height:1px; border:none;"">", IF(AND(Add_CD_Information!B23={1},Add_CD_Information!B48<>""), "<br>", IF(AND(Add_CD_Information!B23={1},Add_CD_Information!B25={2}), "<hr style=""color:#919090; background-color:#919090; height:1px; border:none;"">", "")))
```

Try it out and share if it works.. (or not..)

The trick is..nested-if..

From :

```
  if(a=1,do_A1,do_nothing), if(a=2,do_A2,do_nothing), if(a=3,do_A3,do_nothing)
```

into

```
  if(a=1,do_A1,if(a=2,do_A2,if(a=3,do_A3,do_nothing)))
```

Comment: The 'true' action for formulas 1 and 3 is absolutely the same, so their conditions can be combined using OR() function - it can slightly simplify the final formula.

Comment: yup.. since `do_A1 = do_A3`... it'll become..  `if(OR(a=1,a=3),do_A1,if(a=2,do_A2,do_nothing))` || nice gasp on details @Akina ..  I totally missed that.. [ :